# Overlapping periods - Merging in a continous time series

Tags: sql, algorithm, sorting, oracle11g, overlapping

Recently i am dealing with a overlapping intervals problem.
I have the following situation:

Input:

I have one DB table which contains monthly data like that:

```
StartDate   |   EndDate   |  Value

31.07.2010  |  31.08.2010 |  4500
31.08.2010  |  30.09.2010 |  6500
```

And one table which contains from - to data like that:

```
StartDate   | EndDate    |  Value

16.08.2010  | 29.09.2010 |  9500
```

Output: New table with continous period series like that

```
StartDate   | EndDate    |  Value

31.07.2010  | 15.08.2010 |  4500
16.08.2010  | 29.09.2010 |  9500
30.09.2010  | 30.09.2010 |  6500
```

How you would solve such problem?

My idea would be to make an union of the two tables and sort them by startdate.
Identify the overlapping periods and adjust them.

Is there already an algorithm which i can use for that purpose? Or someone approached already a similar problem?

Thanks,
Patric

Comment: Migrate to dba.stackexchange? Which server - tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, in general, this problem could be solved by selecting all possible start dates into one dataset, and then for each start date get date from next row as end date of the period, something like this:

```
;with cte(StartDate) as (
    select distinct StartDate from Table1
    union
    select distinct EndDate from Table1
    union
    select distinct StartDate from Table2
    union
    select distinct dateadd(dd, 1, EndDate) from Table2
), cte2 as (
    select
        StartDate,
        row_number() over(order by StartDate asc) as rn
    from cte
)
select
    c.StartDate,
    case
        when c2.rn = max(c2.rn) over() then c2.StartDate
        else dateadd(dd, -1, c2.StartDate)
    end as EndDate
from cte2 as c
    inner join cte2 as c2 on c2.rn = c.rn + 1
```

**[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/afec9/7)**

This code is for SQL Server, and the answer is also depends on if it's possible for end of period to be equal to start of next period or not, but you can get general idea.

Comment: @pamaxeed no prob, this code with CTE could be not very fast, you can use some temp table to store dates.

Comment: Hi Roman,
thanks for the answer, it is very helpful for me. Just to understand ur approach: u build a temporary dataset (cte i think it is a transact sql keyword), where u store all StartDate and order it in ascending way. And then u make for each startdate, u retrieve the startdate of the next row and make it as enddate. Is it right? Why u add select distinct dateadd(dd, 1, EndDate) from Table2 ? And in the result the value is missing.